# Value of Behavior Verification

Tags: java, mocking, bdd, mockito

I've been reading up on (and experimenting with) several Java mocking APIs such as Mockito, EasyMock, JMock and PowerMock. I like each of them for different reasons, but have ultimately decided on Mockito. **Please note** though, that this is *not* a question about which framework to use - the question really applies to *any* mocking framework, although the solution will look different as the APIs are (obviously) different.

Like many things, you read the tutorials, you follow the examples, and you tinker around with a few code samples in a sandbox project. But then, when it comes time to actually use the thing, you start to choke - and that's where I am.

I *really*, really like the idea of mocking. And yes, I am aware of the complaints about mocking leading to "brittle" tests that are too heavily coupled with the classes under test. But until I come to such a realization myself, I really want to give mocking a chance to see if it can add some good value to my unit tests.

I'm now trying to actively use mocks in my unit tests. Mockito allows both stubbing and mocking. Let's say we have a `Car` object that has a `getMaxSpeed()` method. In Mockito, we could stub it like so:

```
Car mockCar = mock(Car.class);
when(mockCar.getMaxSpeed()).thenReturn(100.0);
```

This "stubs" the `Car` object to always return `100.0` as the max speed of our car.

**My problem** is that, after writing a handful of unit tests already...all I'm doing is stubbing my collaborators! I'm not using a single mock method (`verify`, etc.) available to me!

I realize that I'm stuck in a "*stubbing state of mind*" and I'm finding it impossible to break. All this reading, and all this excitement building up to using mocks in my unit testing and... I can't think of a single use case for behavior verification.

So I backed up and re-read Fowler's [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) and other BDD-style literatures, and still I'm just "not getting" the value of behavior verification for test double collaborators.

I *know* that I'm missing something, I'm just not sure of what. Could someone give me a concrete example (or even a set of examples!) using, say, this `Car` class, and demonstrate when a behavior-verifying unit test is favorable to a state-verifying test?

Thanks in advance for any nudges in the right direction!

Comment: Could you show us one of your classes? For example, the one that's the client of Car being stubbed above. Then perhaps we could suggest how to test it using mocks.

Comment: Hi Tom - I like JB Nizet's example better than the Car. That example, along with JB's explanation really underscores the source of my confusion. My comment underneath JB's response explains this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the object under test calls a collaborator with a computed value, and the test is supposed to test that the computation is correct, then verifying the mock colaborator is the right thing to do. Example:

```
private ResultDisplayer resultDisplayer;

public void add(int a, int b) {
    int sum = a + b; // trivial example, but the computation might be more complex
    displayer.display(sum);
}
```

Clearly, in this case, you'll have to mock the displayer, and verify that its display method has been called, with the value 5 if 2 and 3 are the arguments of the `add` method.

If all you do with your collaborators is call getters without arguments, or with arguments which are direct inputs of the tested method, then stubbing is probably sufficient, unless the code might get a value from two different collaborators and you want to verify that the appropriate collaborator has been called.

Example:

```
private Computer noTaxComputer;
private Computer taxComputer;

public BigDecimal computePrice(Client c, ShoppingCart cart) {
    if (client.isSubjectToTaxes()) {
        return taxComputer.compute(cart);
    }
    else {
        return noTaxComputer.compute(cart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JB! I think we're now at the root of my confusion. In your second paragraph you state "...you'll have to mock the displayer, and verify that its display method has been called, with the value of 5..." I understand why we need to verify that the displayer is displaying a value of 5...what I'm *not* understanding is why we have to verify that `displayer.display` was even called! Why can't we just write a JUnit assert that `assertEquals(displayer.getDisplay(), 5)`? I just don't see why checking that the `display(int)` method executed adds value to the unit test. Any ideas/counterargs? Thx!

Comment: Because the displayer's display method could do something much more complex than just storing the value in a field accessible through a getter. It could send it to a stream, to an LCD display, to some database, etc. Even if it did store it in a field, constructing the real displayer might be difficult in a test environment because it depends on a database, a JMS engine or other complex infrastructure.

Comment: The displayer could also be invoked several times during the method: once with 2, once with 3 and once with 5. If you want to verify each intermediate state, you have no choice other than mocking the displayer.

Comment: Note also that if you mock the displayer, you have no choice other than to verify each intermediate state. This is one reason why mock-based testing is not always what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I like @JB Nizet's answer, but here's another example.  Suppose you want to persist a Car to a database using Hibernate after making some changes.  So you have a class like this:

```
public class CarController {

  private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

  public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
  }

  public void accelerate(Car car, double mph) {
    car.setCurrentSpeed(car.getCurrentSpeed() + mph);
    hibernateTemplate.update(car);
  }
}
```

To test the accelerate method, you could just use a stub, but you wouldn't have a compete test.

```
public class CarControllerTest {
  @Mock
  private HibernateTemplate mockHibernateTemplate;
  @InjectMocks
  private CarController controllerUT;

  @Test
  public void testAccelerate() {
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setCurrentSpeed(10.0);
    controllerUT.accelerate(car, 2.5);
    assertThat(car.getCurrentSpeed(), is(12.5));
  }
}
```

This test passes and does check the computation, but we don't know if the car's new speed was saved or not.  To do that, we need to add:

```
  verify(hibernateTemplate).update(car);
```

Now, suppose that if you try to accelerate past max speed, you expect the acceleration and the update not to happen.  In that case, you would want:

```
@Test
public void testAcceleratePastMaxSpeed() {
  Car car = new Car();
  car.setMaxSpeed(20.0);
  car.setCurrentSpeed(10.0);
  controllerUT.accelerate(car, 12.5);
  assertThat(car.getCurrentSpeed(), is(10.0));
  verify(mockHibernateTemplate, never()).update(car);
}
```

This test will not pass with our current implementation of CarController, but it shouldn't.  It shows you need to do more work to support this case and that one of the requirements is that you don't try to write to the database in this case.

Basically, verify should be used for exactly what it sounds like - to verify that something happened (or didn't happen).  If the fact that it happened or didn't isn't really what you are trying to test, then skip it.  Take the second example I made.  One could argue that since the value wasn't changed, it doesn't really matter whether update was called or not.  In that case, you can skip the verify step in the second example since the implementation of `accelerate` would be correct either way.

I hope it doesn't sound like I'm making a case for using verify a lot.  It can make your tests very brittle.  But it can also 'verify' that important things that were supposed to happen did happen.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that every test case should contain EITHER

- stubbing, plus one or more `assert`s OR
- one or more `verify`s .

but not both.

It seems to me that in most test classes, you end up with a mixture of "stub and assert" test cases and "verify" test cases.  Whether a test case does a "stub and assert" or does a "verify" depends on whether the value returned by a collaborator is important to the test.  I need two examples to illustrate this.

Suppose I have an `Investment` class, which has a value in dollars.  Its constructor sets the initial value.  It has an `addGold` method, which increases the value of an `Investment` by the amount of gold times the price of gold in dollars per ounce.  I have a collaborator called `PriceCalculator` that calculates the price of gold.  I might write a test like this.

```
public void addGoldIncreasesInvestmentValueByPriceTimesAmount(){
   PriceCalculator mockCalculator = mock( PriceCalculator.class );
   when( mockCalculator.getGoldPrice()).thenReturn( new BigDecimal( 400 ));
   Investment toTest = new Investment( new BigDecimal( 10000 ));
   toTest.addGold( 5 );
   assertEquals( new BigDecimal( 12000 ), toTest.getValue());
}
```

In this case, the result from the collaborator method is important to the test.  We stub it, because we're not testing the `PriceCalculator` at this point.  There's no need to verify, because if the method hadn't been called, the final value of the investment value would not be correct.  So all we need is the `assert`.

Now, suppose there's a requirement that the `Investment` class notifies the IRS whenever anyone withdraws more than $100000 from an `Investment`.  It uses a collaborator called `IrsNotifier` to do this.  So a test for this might look like this.

```
public void largeWithdrawalNotifiesIRS(){
   IrsNotifier mockNotifier = mock( IrsNotifier.class );
   Investment toTest = new Investment( new BigDecimal( 200000 ));
   toTest.setIrsNotifier( mockNotifier );
   toTest.withdraw( 150000 );
   verify( mockNotifier ).notifyIRS();
}
```

In this case, the test doesn't care about the return value from the collaborator method `notifyIRS()`.  Or maybe it's void.  What matters is just that the method got called.  For a test like this, you'll use a `verify`.  There may be stubbing in a test like this (to set up other collaborators, or return values from different methods), but it's unlikely that you'll ever want to stub the same method that you verify.

If you find yourself using both stubbing and verification on the same collaborator method, you should probably ask yourself why.  What is the test really trying to prove?  Does the return value matter to the test?  Because this is usually a testing code smell.

Hope these examples are helpful to you.